# Get number of calculations in a program

Tags: python

Please redirect me to right place if I'm in the wrong place, but I have a presentation to showcase an application that I built. The audience loves to hear big numbers, so just to impress I'm trying to put in a number which gives an idea of calculations that are being done in the entire application demo.

I can use number of calculations the processor is capable of * time taken but I was looking for a more direct way. 
If it helps the code of my application is in Python.

Comment: It depends on what you consider a calculation in your context

Comment: If you break it down all the way to the bottom, you're basically looking for how many Assembly commands are done over the course of the program?

Comment: I think you should use data structure and algorithms techniques. Counting number of calculation depends on the main arithmetic and logic and calculating operations in a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using one of [python's builtin profilers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) could help you, bearing in mind they're made for optimizing code and maybe too high-level for you. `cProfile` is one example and it can give you the number of times functions were called.

*Note: there are a lot of good, easy tutorials out there on good first steps with these complex libraries*